# How to set SaveSentMessageFolder using Exchange EWS

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

When i create a draft mail using CreateEmail() call, how can I pre-set a destination save folder so that the final sent item will be saved to when user press "Send" and outlook ?

In outlook, it is under Options -> "Save Sent Item To", but i don't know how to do it in EWS

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EWS you can specify which folder you want a message your sending saved to. If your using the EWS Managed API you do this via the Overload for Send or SendAndSaveCopy otherwise the default will be the drafts folder and sent-items folder of the current security principal.

If your creating the draft with EWS and sending with Outlook then you would need to set the PR_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc842003.aspx to the HexId of the folder you want Outlook to save the message to

eg

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition  PR_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0E0A,MapiPropertyType.Binary);
        TestMove.SetExtendedProperty(PR_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID,ConvertHexStringToByteArray("00000000BE1CDD3D9606274890F3DE4B7DDFBE490100751047FD18EA304D9D40B1428BAC20D00000364670AA0000"));
```

(this is the same property that Outlook sets)

you need to make sure you use the HexId of the Folder not the EWSId to get the HexId you can use convertId eg

```
        AlternateId ai = new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, folder.Id.UniqueId, "gscales@datarumble.com");
        AlternateId Convertedai = (AlternateId)service.ConvertId(ai, IdFormat.HexEntryId);
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition  PR_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x0E0A,MapiPropertyType.Binary);
        TestMove.SetExtendedProperty(PR_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID, ConvertHexStringToByteArray(Convertedai.UniqueId));

        internal static byte[] ConvertHexStringToByteArray(string hexString)
    {
        if (hexString.Length % 2 != 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "The binary key cannot have an odd number of digits: {0}", hexString));
        }

        byte[] HexAsBytes = new byte[hexString.Length / 2];
        for (int index = 0; index < HexAsBytes.Length; index++)
        {
            string byteValue = hexString.Substring(index * 2, 2);
            HexAsBytes[index] = byte.Parse(byteValue, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return HexAsBytes;
    }
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: thank you. this should be exactly what i wanted. but I have a FolderId object say FFF
my call to SetExtendedProperty(PR_SENTMAIL_ENTRYID, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FFF.UniqueId));
doesn't do the job. Any idea?

Comment: You need to make sure you convert the EWSid to HexEntryId (same as the PR_EntryId) of the folder. I've posted a sample above